# Entity Framework Core many-to-many query produces least performant query

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I have a `User` and a `Role` table. They have a many-to-many relationship and EF Core 5 produces a join table automatically. I have a scenario that I need to get Role names that belong to specific user.

I am writing the following query:

```
await dbContext.Role
               .AsNoTracking().IgnoreQueryFilters()
               .Where(x => x.Users.Any(y => y.Id == user.Id))
               .Select(x => x.Name).ToListAsync();
```

which produces the following SQL

```
SELECT [r].[Name]
FROM [Role] AS [r]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [UserRole] AS [u]
    INNER JOIN [User] AS [u0] ON [u].[UsersId] = [u0].[Id]
    WHERE ([r].[Id] = [u].[RolesId]) AND ([u0].[Id] = 1)
)
```

I want to to produce following query

```
SELECT [r].[Name]
FROM [Role] AS [r]
INNER JOIN [UserRole] AS [u] on u.RolesId = r.Id
WHERE u.UsersId = 1
```

which is faster.

How can this be done?

Comment: Could you post your user and role classes pls?

Comment: It is possible by accessing the join entity directly inside the L2E query, but I'm not even going to post it, since it is against all the benefits of using the ORM and the implicit join entity. The EF Core generated `EXISTS` query contains one redundant join for this scenario, but otherwise is equivalent of the desired, and it's the database query optimizer job to further optimize it (and eventually remove the redundant join).

Comment: @Sergey How it would help? Take any standard M2M example, for instance `Post` / `Tag` from [Many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) documentation, and what? You'll get the same SQL translation as OP. Because this is the way EF Core works. What are you going to do - posting some "Try this"?

Comment: @IvanStoev  I was thinking that since useridId is used  maybe it will be easier instead of context.Roles to use context.Users.

Comment: @Sergey I see. That's the first thing which comes to mind. But... the only difference is that it produces a `JOIN` instead of `EXISTS`, but still joins the 3 tables instead of 2 as OP wishes.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for info. This is why I would never use only two classes for m-to-m. A lasy man  aways does everything twice.

Answer (score 0):

Query the join table

```
dbContext.UserRoles.Where(ur => ur.UserId == user.UserId).Select(ur => ur.Role.Name);
```

Comment: They don't have explicit join table to query.