# Entity Framework Core 6 many-to-many relationship navigation property exclusion

Tags: many-to-many, navigation-properties, asp.net-core-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I have two entities linked that have a many-to-many relationship as shown here:

```
public class Product
{
    //Omitted code...
    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> ingredients { get; set; }
}

public class Ingredient
{
    // Omitted code...
    public virtual ICollection<Product> products { get; set; }
}
```

My question is: I want to load only `Product.ingredients` navigation property, and I don't want to load the other side of the relation which is `ingredient.Products`. I want to keep the many-to-many relationship. How can I prevent the `ingredient.Products` navigation property from being loaded ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "I don't want to load the other side of the relation which is ingredient.Products" What do you mean about this? You don't want the Ingredient has products  ? Can you give an example to explain more about what you want?

Comment: You can't prevent EF Core doing that because it is by design. And not only for many-to-many, but for any relationship navigation properties. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42327515/ef-core-returns-null-relations-until-direct-access/42329028#42329028 and linked documentation. Go fix the place having issues with circular references (probably json serializer).

Comment: @IvanStoev I have a different use case here: with the M2M, to get an efficient query without a sub-select requires using two O2M mappings and an explicit mapping table.  Then the navigation goes through the mapping table and the query does not have a sub-select.  However, if at query time it were possible to tell EF "In this query, I only care about going in this direction", it seems that it should achieve the same result, no?  This question is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67285325/entity-framework-core-many-to-many-query-produces-least-performant-query.

Comment: @CharlesChen The question is not what will be nice to have, but what EF is giving you. Here the subject is navigation property populating in memory, which is done by design by EF process called "navigation property fixup", which can happen even after executing tracking query, and the executing another tracking query which loads related entities into change tracker. The "related" question you are referring to is different - there is simply EF Core query translator defect.

Comment: "there is simply EF Core query translator defect." appreciate the confirmation.  Found a related GH issue for future travelers: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17622